# How to show a generated PDF file with in the browser or outside the browser in windows?

Tags: java, windows, firefox, pdf

In my application, I want show a printable PDF acrobat file with in the browser or outside the browser other than saving. In Firefox by default it will ask for save or open, I don't need that dialogue. I want to show that file preferably outside the browser. Can you please suggest me.

Thanks,
Vara Kumar.PJD

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can suggest to the browser that it should show the PDF in a window rather than offering to download it via the [`Content-Disposition` header](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2183.txt):

```
response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline");
```

The "inline" value suggests that the content be rendered inline (as opposed to the "attachment" value suggesting the browser offer to download it).

Once you've made the suggestion to the browser, the browser may or may not accept your suggestion, depending on its implementation and possibly its user preferences.

Comment: Sorry T.J. Crowder I am not getting any positive result with that content-disposition inline

Comment: @varakumar.pjd: Sorry to hear that. V. strange. It works for me in a very similar use-case. I have an application where sometimes I want to open a new window containing the PDF, and other times I want the browser to download the PDF. I have a link to a page that generates the PDF, and I have a `target` attribute set to `_blank`. I successfully use that header to control what happens when the user clicks the link. With standard IE6, IE7, Firefox, and Chrome settings it seems to work.

Comment: Can you tell me the meaning of Content-Disposition because I don't know about it

Comment: @varakumar.pjd: StackOverflow really needs to underline links, the words "`Content-Disposition` header" in my answer are a link to the RFC for it, which explain it in full detail. Basically, what it means is, "here's what you should do with this content I'm sending you."

Comment: Hay, T.J.Crowder that  "Content-Disposition", "inline" is working fine but how to set my own name to that PDF file. I written as "Content-Disposition", "inline; Filename="+getFileName() but it is not working in firefox but it is working in IE.

Comment: @varakumar.pjd: Firefox might be being difficult about capitalization. `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=myfilename.pdf` (note that "filename" is in lower case) works for me in Firefox. I'd also be sure to keep the filename simple (no spaces, for instance). If that's not it, I recommend posting a new question and showing the response headers that aren't working. Best,

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is something you can control from your app, i think this is the matter of environment/browser/plugins that users are using... but zou can open new window for your pdf by javascript like this [link](http://www.webcredible.co.uk/user-friendly-resources/dom-scripting/pdf-new-window.shtml)

Answer (score 0):

You can do like some thing like this.

```
        response.setContentType("application/pdf"); 
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream("answerconnect.pdf"); 
        OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream(); 
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024]; 
        int len; 
        while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) { 
            out.write(buf, 0, len); 
        } 
        in.close();
```

Comment: I fail to see how this answers the question. You are posting a code snippet (without context!) to send a file through an OutputStream. This is not what the question was about.